# ID элементов в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Есть вывод в ListView из базы данных. 
Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на элемент из списка, передавалось в следующую активность не position, а id элемента который был у него в базе данных.

На пример:

```
1 элемент (id из db - 12 --- по нажатию на этот элемент передавало не position(0),а id 12
2 элемент (id из db - 43)--- по нажатию на этот элемент передавало не position(1),а id 43
3 элемент (id из db-145)--- по нажатию на этот элемент передавало не position(2),а id 145
и тд.
```

Comment: Что за бред?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long id = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).getId();

}
```

как то так, смотря какие данные ты передаешь в адаптер

---

```
  public class ContractDB {
public static class Groups {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "groups";
    private String name;
    private long id;
    private long id_sprint;
    private int min;
    private int max;

    // geters and seters 
 ...........
    public class GroupsColumns implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String NAME = "group_name";
        public static final String ID_SPRINT = "id_sprint";
        public static final String MIN = "min";
        public static final String MAX = "max";

    }
}
// others tables

}
```

и в адаптере работаю непосредственно с объектами Groups

Comment: А как задать списку индикаторы чтобы их можно было передать

Comment: в текучем проекте есть похожая задача, описал контракты бд, свой адаптер и в listview загружаю объекты, не знаю насколько это правильно, но работать удобно

Comment: Толи я не правильно объяснил проблему, то ли Вы меня не правильно поняли. Сначала нужно построить список с нужными ID (из db), а потом уже при нажатии на список получить этот ID, ну или как-то так 
Вот моя Activity: [Работа с базой данных в Android](http://hashcode.ru/questions/247990/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-android)  
из построенного списка нужно перейти и передать нажатый на элемент из списка, а там выбрать список по переданному id из б

Comment: Так понимаю нет ответов на мой Вопрос??

Comment: в бд есть данные у которых есть _id (куда уж без него ), получив эти данные выводим их в listview, по нажатию на элемент в listview хотим знать какой _id соответствует данному элементу ?  правильно понимаю ?

Comment: В бд для меня требуемые ид такого рода 410, 352, 481, 280, 594 и так далее, Вывели данные. У них получается позиция и ид назначаются  0,1,2,3,4, и тд. а мне нужно им присвоить 410, 352, 481, 280, 594, а потом передать в другую активити ид нажатого элемента. Вопрос в том как им присвоить ид. Или если есть другой метод. Мне нужно одно из этих ид (410, 352, 481, 280, 594) в другой активности для вывода из бд данных...

Comment: ну так я уже описал - описывается класс контракта - просто класс описывающий данные выборки, если в listview выводим только одну строку, то в классе перегружаем toString() если выводится таблица с несколькими столбцами то наследуем свой адаптер
у адаптера есть свойство getItem которое возвращает объект, вот у него то  и узнается вся нужная информация - _id, или любая другая информация

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет о SQLite и адаптере на основе `SimpleCursorAdapter` , то четвертый аргумент колбэка, возвращающего клик по айтему списка и есть ID  из БД

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View .view, int position, long id) {
}
```

long id - ID записи в БД по айтему в списке которого кликнули

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решается очень просто "в лоб", автор больше затуманил ситуацию.

```
 ЛистВью.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id)
        {
            cursor = Адаптер.getCursor();
            переменная = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))
        }
    });
```

Ничего никому не нужно присваивать, а работать с этим самым _id везде.