# Взять данные с Item ListView

Tags: java, android

```
apapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this,R.layout.info_layout,model.ReaderWithDateBaseLite (this),new String[]{"summa","description","nameCoast"},new int[]{R.id.tvSumma,R.id.description,R.id.tvName},0);
```

Использую для вывода данных.
В дальнейшем использую обработчик при нажатии, что-бы изменить или удалить данные, но  `parent.getAdapter ().getItem (position);` возвращает просто название бд.
А мне бы `id` взять.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612234/177345

Comment: intent.putExtra("key", "Text-file");